# Save object with Hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, object-persistence

I just wanna ask know how its possible to create object after creating your database with Hibernate annotations?

When i run the code below, it creates the database with the objects, but when i run the second time it just creates exactly the same, and none new objects are added? How come? How do i create objects using annotations with the method .save, after creating the database with annotations? Or is it not possible to do so with annotations?

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Adress adress = new Adress("Streetname", "postcode");

        Person person1 = new Person("Peter Hanks", adress);
        Person person2 = new Person("Sophie Hanks", adress);

        session.save(person1);
        session.save(person2);
        transaction.commit();



    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

Heres the code person.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
private long id;
private String navn;
private Adresse adresse;

public Person() {
}

public Person(String navn, Adresse adresse) {
    this.navn = navn;
    this.adresse = adresse;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name= "adresse_id", nullable = false)
public Adresse getAdresse() {
    return adresse;
}

public void setAdresse(Adresse adresse) {
    this.adresse = adresse;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name= "id")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "navn", nullable= false, length= 100)
public String getNavn() {
    return navn;
}

public void setNavn(String navn) {
    this.navn = navn;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 29 * hash + (this.navn != null ? this.navn.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 29 * hash + (this.adresse != null ? this.adresse.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}





@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if ((this.navn == null) ? (other.navn != null) : !this.navn.equals(other.navn)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.adresse != other.adresse && (this.adresse == null || !this.adresse.equals(other.adresse))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to show us how you've written and annotated your `Person` and `Adress` (sic) objects.

If you've written "correct" `equals()` and `hashcode()` implementations (i.e. that don't look at the `@Id` of the object) then your `save()` calls will do nothing the second time around because the objects you've asked to save already exist in the database.

Comment: I dont get it.. I am using @GeneratedValue, so it shouldnt be a problem. The database is counting up the id, so it cant be the same objects??

Comment: Between running the first and second time, change "Peter" to "Paul" and "Sophie" to "Sarah". Do you get more objects now?

Comment: no, running second time the first objects still stands in the database.. the second added are not recorded??? I just added the code for person.class

Comment: Odd. Code looks OK, how are you getting Hibernate to build your schema? In your question you say "it creates the database with the objects" - which hbm2ddl mode are you using?

Comment: ok.. i am using create.. <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

Comment: another thing i just realised, is that when i just change the adress, it just updates the name in the database???

Comment: OK something strange is going on. Just to rule out some possible causes, can I suggest you add some `equals()` and `hashcode()` implementations to your objects that **do not** include the `id` field in their calculations. This has always been a good idea when dealing with persisted entities.

Comment: I just tried with hashcode() and equals() and it didnt change anything.. i have added the code for the methods for person.class

Comment: I just found out another way to do let hibernate know classes i have annotated.. I added som code in my HibernateUtil.class, just added addAnnotatedClass(person.class) and know thereis no problem... But thx for you help anyway...

Answer (score 0):

just changed the settings for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto from create to create-update, and now theres no problem...